# Combining Plotly and ggplot2 charts with Patchwork in one Facet

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, subplot, patchwork

I want to combine two charts prepared with Plotly and ggplot2 into one PDF. Below, you can see the code for the preparation of the charts:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(patchwork)

## 1.Plotly

dt=data.frame(
  types= rep("stories",10),
  kind= c('kind_1','kind_2','kind_3','kind_1','kind_2','kind_3','kind_1','kind_2','kind_3','kind_1'),
  values=seq(1:10))

Treemap_plotly<-plot_ly(data = dt,
                 type= "treemap",
                 values= ~values,
                 labels= ~kind,
                 parents=  ~types,
                 domain= list(column=0),
                 name = " ",
                 textinfo="label+value+percent parent")%>%
            layout(title="Treemap")


## 2.ggplot2

df1 <- data.frame(dose=c("D0.5", "D1", "D2"),
                 len=c(4.2, 10, 29.5))


barchart_ggplot2<-ggplot(data=df1, aes(x=dose, y=len)) +
          geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="steelblue")+
          geom_text(aes(label=len), vjust=-0.3, size=3.5)+
          theme_minimal()
```

Now, I want to combine them into one facet plot using the patchwork library. Below, you can see the command:

```
# Combine both

(Treemap_plotly/barchart_ggplot2)
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. Below is my desired graph:

[image]

[image]

Comment: To my knowledge, `patchwork` can only combine `ggplot` and/or `grob` objects, not `plotly` objects. You can try to either build your treemap in `ggplot2` and then use `patchwork`, or if you need to keep the interactivity of the `plotly` object for some later use, consider starting with a `ggplot` object (for use in patchwork) and later converting to a `plotly` object using the `ggplotly()` function.

Answer (score 1):

`patchwork` does not work with `plotly` objects. It's possible to create the treemap in `ggplot2` but it involves some more work or using packages like `treemapify`.

We could save the treemap graph as an image and then use `gridExtra` to put the plots side by side:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(magick)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

Treemap_plotly_file <- tempfile(fileext = ".png")
#export is soft deprecated, but for now it's the best option
suppressWarnings(invisible(export(Treemap_plotly, file = Treemap_plotly_file))) 
my_img <- image_read(Treemap_plotly_file)

barchart_ggplot2<- barchart_ggplot2 + theme(plot.margin = margin(1,0.5,1,0, "cm"))

grid.arrange(rasterGrob(my_img), barchart_ggplot2, widths = c(0.6, 0.4))
```

[image]

But this will look janky depending on the size of the plots and whatnot. So, I'd suggest creating both plots with `plotly` and then use `subplot`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

Treemap_plotly <- plot_ly(data = dt, type= "treemap", 
                        values= ~values, labels= ~kind, parents=  ~types,
                        domain= list(column=0), name = " ",
                        textinfo="label+value+percent parent") %>% 
  layout(title = list(text = "Treemap", x = 0.1))

barchart_plotly <- df1 %>% 
                    mutate(clr = "#619CFF") %>% 
                    plot_ly(data = , x = ~dose, y = ~len, 
                           color = ~clr, colors = "#619CFF", 
                           type = "bar", showlegend = F,
                           text = ~sprintf("<b>%s</b>", len), 
                           textfont = list(color = "black"),
                           textposition='outside')

subplot(Treemap_plotly, barchart_plotly, widths = c(0.6, 0.3))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>